# Connect to sqlplus with another linux user than oracle

Tags: linux, oracle, database-connection, sqlplus, privileges

I installed Oracle with sqlplus with user oracle (linux - CentOS). If I try to connect to database being oracle everything goes as expected (sqlplus / as sysdba for example), but I need to do the same thing (maybe not as sysdba, but as a user from database) being another linux user. I added this second user to group "dba", but still nothing. If, being secondUser, I enter "sqlplus username/password" I get this:

> ERROR ORA-12547 TNS: lost contact

Can someone (please) guide me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: See [**How to resolve ORA-12547: TNS :lost contact when try to connect to Oracle**](http://lalitkumarb.com/2015/11/03/ora-12547-tns-lost-contact-when-try-to-connect-to-oracle/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely it is due to incorrect **privileges** at OS level. The **Oracle** file in the **$ORACLE_HOME/bin** directory should have following privileges:

```
-rwsr-s--x
```

You could check it like:

```
cd $ORACLE_HOME/bin
ls -lrt oracle
```

If you see any difference, then do:

```
chmod 6751 oracle
ls -lrt oracle
```

For more details, see [**How to resolve ORA-12547: TNS :lost contact when try to connect to Oracle**](http://lalitkumarb.com/2015/11/03/ora-12547-tns-lost-contact-when-try-to-connect-to-oracle/)